# Need to convert Win32_PrintJob - TimeSubmitted to a standard Date/Time format using PowerShell

Tags: powershell

```
gwmi -Query "Select * From Win32_PrintJob Where DriverName = 'Lexmark Universal v2 PS3'" | select Document, Size, TotalPages, TimeSubmitted  | epCsv -Path C:\PrintJobs2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

"TimeSubmitted" shows up as:  "20220722094242.976000-240"

I've seen other variation of using `$_.ConvertToDateTime` or `DateTime.ParseExact("20130608204517.699000-300".Split('.')[0], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", null);`  but not sure how to format it correctly with my code above...

tysm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That date format is called DMTF datetime and represents a date or time value in a string in DMTF date/time format:

- `yyyymmddHHMMSS.mmmmmmsUUU`, where
- `yyyymmdd` is the date in year/month/day
- `HHMMSS` is the time in hours/minutes/seconds
- `mmmmmm` is the number of microseconds in 6 digits
- `sUUU` is a sign (+ or -) and a 3-digit UTC offset.

This value maps to the [CimType DateTime type (101)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.management.cimtype?view=dotnet-plat-ext-6.0).

Luckily, there is a way to convert that to a normal DateTime object in the current time zone of the system using

```
[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime("20220722094242.976000-240")
```

Your code can then be

```
Get-WmiObject -Query "Select * From Win32_PrintJob Where DriverName = 'Lexmark Universal v2 PS3'" | 
Select-Object Document, Size, TotalPages, 
              @{Name = 'TimeSubmitted'; Expression = {[System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime($_.TimeSubmitted)}} -ExcludeProperty TimeSubmitted |
Export-Csv -Path C:\PrintJobs2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```

**Note:**

Unfortunately, the ManagementDateTimeConverter returns a datetime with its `.Kind` set to `Unspecified` where that shoud really be `Local`.
In your case this doesn't matter, but if you want to use this datetime object in further calculations, you can force set it to Local using:

```
$date = [System.Management.ManagementDateTimeConverter]::ToDateTime("20220722094242.976000-240")
[datetime]::SpecifyKind($date, 'Local')
```

Comment: you guys are amazing!  thank you so much!  I love the depth of knowledge and the way you broke it down, a sincere thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not able to test myself but give this a try

```
gwmi -Query "Select * From Win32_PrintJob Where DriverName = 'Lexmark Universal v2 PS3'" | select Document, Size, TotalPages, @{n="TimeSubmitted";e={[DateTime]::ParseExact($_.TimeSubmitted.Split('.')[0], "yyyyMMddHHmmss", $null) }}  | epCsv -Path C:\PrintJobs2.csv -NoTypeInformation
```